# Dotnet tool "zsh: command not found: libman" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-7.0, libman

I am developing a .Net project and I need to use the libman tool. I write the dotnet tool install -g Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Cli command via the terminal, the installation is completed, I check it with the dotnet tool list -g command and the tool appears to be installed, but despite this, when I try to run the libman command, "zsh: command not found: libman" I'm getting the error. What is the reason?

**dotnet tool install -g**

**dotnet tool list -g**

**Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Cli**

### Package Id                            Version      Commands

microsoft.web.librarymanager.cli      2.1.175      libman

**zsh: command not found: libman**

Comment: Hi @alperenaydin! Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's great that you found a solution. You can post it as an answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution,

> sudo ln -s ~/.dotnet/tools/libman /usr/local/bin/libman

, run this code, you can use libman commands

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Same issue with me, but with swagger , command not found - using Ubuntu under WSL2 - creating the symbolic link resolved the issue